# When were the x-wings built?

Tags: star-wars

I've seen a bit about the history of x-wings but never saw any date when the prototypes and the full production runs came into existence (in galaxy date) so is there any official date there? (now naturally considered legends instead of full canon)

Comment: There's a potted history here (complete with dates). Note that this article is a **complete dog's breakfast** with non-canon EU elements all over the canon page; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-65_X-wing_starfighter

Comment: hit me but where do the dates there stand? I looked over it but didnt find a date an hour ago

Comment: In the history section it mentions that prototypes were liberated during the [Battle of Fresia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Fresia) in 1BBY. That's when the Rebels started using them. For the record, the source is the PC game [Star Wars : Empire At War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Empire_at_War)

Comment: tnx that means 1BBY is the date they were created then. hmmm quite a lot happened there then 1 BBY

Comment: But the X-Wings are used in RotS @ 1:46  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWoGkrt5Upg#t=107 how could they have not been used until 1BBY when they were used during the Battle over Coruscant?

Comment: Those are not X-Wings in RotS.  Those are the ARC-170 starfighters, reminiscent of X-Wings, but bigger, slower and far less maneuverable, so probably an ancestor design.

Comment: @BBlake, ah.  Did not know that

Answer (score 2):

There are no precise time about there construction but it was sometime between [1 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/1_BBY) and [0 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/0_BBY)

Thanks to continued upgrades to the basic design and improved tactics, the X-wing series remained one of the galaxy's predominant multi-role starfighters for over 40 years.

Two months after the [Battle of Yavin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Yavin), [Incom corporation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Incom_Corporation) was able to donate prototype X-wings to the fledgling Rebel Alliance which were stored in isolation (**0 BBY**). They were renowned for their production of the T-65 X-wing starfighter, which became their logo.

> "Time to retire those old Z-95s! These X-wings can handle anything the
>   Empire can throw at us!"
>
> ―[Captain Raymus Antilles[src]](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Raymus_Antilles) after the victory at Fresia (**1 BBY**).

The [Battle of Fresia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Fresia) was a decisive engagement early in the Galactic Civil War that marked the beginning of the use of X-wing starfighters by the Alliance to Restore the Republic.

> "The Incom T-65 X-wing is the fighter that killed the Death Star. An
>   almost perfect balance of speed, maneuverability, and defensive
>   shielding make it the fighter of choice for Rogue Squadron."
>
> ―[General Carlist Rieekan[src]](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Carlist_Rieekan)

I've done a lot of research and from what I could find these T-65 X-Wings (wich were the 1st x-wing starfighter) were made from modifying the [Z-95 Headhunter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z-95_Headhunter) in the early 1 BBY by Incom Corporation.

The Z-95 Headhunter
[image: Z-95]

The T-65 X-Wing
[image: T-65]

Though they look pretty similar, the Z-95 canot open its wings. They modified it so it could perform on near equal terms with the Empire's high-performance [TIE fighters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Series) when handled by an experienced pilot.

Just to compliment, TIE series starfighters may have been tested as early as [29 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/29_BBY). TIE fighters were used on [Imperial Victory-class Star Destroyers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory-class_Star_Destroyer), such as the [Strikefast](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Strikefast) as early as [19 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/19_BBY)